# ASP Session variables: Is "" same as IsEmpty?

Tags: asp-classic, session-variables, is-empty, defaultifempty

In ASP an uninitialized Session variable Is Empty.  I know that the correct way to check for a Session value, and remove a value, is the following:

```
IF NOT IsEmpty(Session("myVar")) THEN
  ' Go ahead and use Session("myVar")
  ...
  ' Now if we're all done with myVar then remove it:
  Session.Contents.Remove("myVar")
END IF
```

I've inherited a codebase where Application and Session variables are typically set `= ""` after use, and all tests for a value are of the form `(Sessions("myVar") = "")`.  This test *appears* to work when the Session variable has not been declared ... or maybe it's just working by dumb luck.

**Is it safe to use comparison with the empty string to test for a Session variable?  I.e., is the following "practically as good" as the correct method shown above?**

```
IF Session("myVar") <> "" THEN
  ' Go ahead and use Session("myVar")
  ...
  ' Now if we're all done with myVar then blank it:
  Session("myVar") = ""
END IF
```

Or should I refactor the codebase so that:

1. All tests to determine whether a Session variable has been set are of the form `IsEmpty(Session("myVar"))`
2. All session variables are `Remove`d and not set `= ""`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Empty` is a strange beast: it is simultaneously equal to both `""` and `0`. Seriously, try it:

```
dim x, y, z
x = Empty
y = ""
z = 0
Response.Write (x = y) AND (x = z)
```

It'll write out "True".

This means that testing for `Not IsEmpty(myvar)` is equivalent to testing `myvar <> ""`, but `IsEmpty(myvar)` is **not** equivalent to `myvar = ""`. Whether that mostly-theoretical difference bothers you or not is something only you can answer, but personally, I wouldn't waste time on refactoring.

---

If you *do* decide to refactor, I would suggest forgetting about `IsEmpty` and `IsNull` and whatnot, and just using the `& ""` "hack":

```
If Session("myvar") & "" <> "" Then
```

This'll transparently handle Nulls *and* Empties without you needing to write a whole bunch of code.

Comment: I tend to avoid using `IsEmpty()` and opt instead for `Len(value & "") > 0`.

Comment: @Lankymart - Yeah, I'm seeing a lot of `value&""` to protect against cases where `value` might be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

No, it could be not safe. Perhaps you need to use functions: `IsNull`, `IsEmpty` and `VarType`

> IsNull -- returns True if expression is Null, that is, it contains no
> valid data; otherwise, IsNull returns False. If expression consists of
> more than one variable, Null in any constituent variable causes True
> to be returned for the entire expression.
>
> VarType -- Returns a value indicating the subtype of a variable.
>
> IsEmpty -- returns True if the variable is uninitialized, or is
> explicitly set to Empty; otherwise, it returns False. False is always
> returned if expression contains more than one variable.

Please take a look at [What is the '<>' asp operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922176/what-is-the-asp-operator/30923091#30923091)