# ifnull not enough for testing for numerical rs

Tags: asp-classic

I have a function, which is supposed to return zero, if the input cannot be converted to an integer.

But sometimes it fails, if the field from a resultset is not a proper value, whatever it is.

```
Function nulblank(str)
    dim val
    if IsNull(str) then
        val=0
    else
        str = trim(str)
        if isNumeric(str) then
            val = cDbl(str)
        else
            val = 0
        end if
    end if
    nulblank = val
end function
```

I get an error 0x80020009 on str = trim(str)

This function is only called on

```
set rs = conn.execute(sql)
i = nulblank(rs("somefield"))
```

How can I make this function "failsafe", so it never dies, but returns 0 on "bad" values?

I guess I could do on error resume next and if Err.Number <> 0 then something.

But what can be in a rs("somefield") which is not null, but cannot be trim()'ed?

Comment: You tried `i = nulblank(rs("somefield") & "")`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922176/what-is-the-asp-operator/30923091#30923091

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663205/asp-session-variables-is-same-as-isempty/38720449#38720449

Comment: @zam doesn't even need the `IsNull()` check which isn't doing what the OP expects anyway *(as your answer details)*.

Comment: `But what can be in a rs("somefield") which is not null, but cannot be trim()'ed?` should not be error if it's not null.

Comment: @zam Simple `Null` in VBScript and `ADODB` provider `Null` are not the same thing. Which is why `& ""` bypasses it as you are always passing a string.

Comment: I've had `IsNumeric()` return False for a field that was specifically `Cast`-ed to `numeric`. As Lankymart said, database data types and ASP datatypes are not always similar/compatible enough. `& ""` really is your best friend when it comes to data type detection/conversion, because it gives you a dependable baseline - the only way it won't turn something into a string is if said something is an array.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually relates to an empty recordset.

You should check that the recordset has a row before attempting to retrieve a column value, eg:

```
set rs = conn.execute(sql)
if not rs.eof then
    i = nulblank(rs("somefield"))
end if
```